# Estimating the average error hyper plane for neural network

Tags: neural-network

I have a neural network of which i need to estimate the average hyperplane which indicates the average error over all training examples. The training examples are present all at once. For example if i have a one variable function then i need to find the line which denotes the average value of the function. For my application exact average is not required, a heuristic will also do.

Average output of each output neuron over all training examples. where:

```
t_j' = sum_i_1_to_N (t_i_j)/N
```

Sum of squared difference between the average output (calculated above) of each output neuron for the training examples and the actual target output of each example:

```
Avg Error = 1/2 * sum_i_1_to_N (sum_j_1_C (t_j' - t_i_j))^2)
```

This is a heuristic but I want to know how it will also keep the `Avg Error` constant for a certain training set.

Is this way valid ? Is there any better way to find the average (kind of) of a neural network for a fixed training set ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your problem, I'd say no.

> Avg Error = 1/2 * sum_i_1_to_N (sum_j_1_C (t_j' - t_i_j))^2)

The above looks to more like a standard deviation than an average. That won't tell you much, consider this:

`Error = sum_i_1_to_N (sum_j_1_C ( ABS(c_j' - t_i_j) ))`

(where `c_j` is the correct output at j)

Now you're looking at computationally cheap number that serves the same purpose of a numerical mean (you could divide all numbers by N to get the actually mean, but why would you bother?). The RMS would look like this:

`ErrorRMS = sum_i_1_to_N (sum_j_1_C ( ABS(e_j' - t_i_j)^2 ))`

Whether you want an RMS or an average will depend on your problem, but more often than not, it won't matter much (sets with lower RMS will *tend* to have a lower mean anyway, so you're *mostly* evolving the same thing).

Note that `Error` and `ErrorRMS` These aren't actually averages or RMS values, but they rank the same and they're cheaper to obtain.

That aside, assuming you have a neural network with multiple outputs, operating over multiple steps (thereby producing the error hyperplane you're talking about), then I would first and foremost suggest structuring the problem a little differently.

The only reason you should have a neural network with more than 1 output is if the outputs can only be understood in connection with each other. Otherwise you should be training `N` neural networks, rather than 1 neural network with `N` outputs. That having been said, if you can't produce a single error to describe *all* the outputs of a network over a single step, maybe you should be dividing it into multiple networks? Then you can simply take the RMS or straight average of the errors over the samples on which the network is tested.

Does this make sense?